# Creating backup of database in Query Browser

Tags: mysql, database, backup

I want to create a backup of my mysql database that's created in Query Browser, but I just can't figure out how.

This isn't about setting up automatic backup of the db, it's about saving the whole database to a file, so that I can send it to a friend who needs to have look at it (it's only local access so far).

What I have found so far on the net is that I should click Tools -> MySQL Administrator. The problem is that MySQL Administrator is greyed out and unclickable. So, is it the right way to go through MySQL Administrator and if so, how can I make it clickable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can create backup through query. And that way you could do that against a button click in c#, java or php etc... I have done it for backing up data and can guide you for full db backup as well

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need the query browser to backup your DB. Use MySQL Dump:

```
mysqldump -u root -p dbname > outfile.sql
```